# Ansible template error while templating string: unexpected

Tags: ansible

I have the following directory

```
named.0.102.10.reverse
named.0.103.10.reverse
named.0.104.10.reverse
named.0.2.10.reverse
named.dreamhosts
```

That's my code

```
---
- name: Check if the dns reverse file exist based on the ips
  find:
    paths: '/tmp/test_dns'
    patterns: '^named\.'
    use_regex: True
  register: find_results

- name: print find_results
  debug: var="{{item.path}}"
  with_items: '{{find_results.files}}'
```

I get the following error

```
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '/'. String: {{/tmp/test_dns/named.5.104.10.reverse}}"}
```

It's seems to be a bug but after further research the bug was fixed on my version.

So maybe, i though the problem was between the chair and the keyboard :-) . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to use template in the value of the `var` parameter. It should contain a variable name:

```
- name: print find_results
  debug: var=item.path
  with_items: '{{find_results.files}}'
```

Writing `"{{item.path}}"` you provide the variable value instead of its name and Ansible gets confused.